# scipy's fsolve gives answers that aren't roots

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am trying to find roots of a function in python using fsolve:

```
import math
import scipy
def f(a):
    eq=-2*a**2 - 2*a**2*(math.sin(25*a**(1/4)))**2 - 2*a**2*(math.cos(25*a**(1/4)))**2 - 2*math.exp(-25*a**(1/4))*a**2*math.cos(25*a**(1/4)) - 2*math.exp(25*a**(1/4))*a**2*math.cos(25*a**(1/4))
    return eq

print(f(scipy.optimize.fsolve(f,10)))
```

and it returns the following value:

```
[1234839.75468454]
```

That doesn't seem very close to 0 to me... Does it simply lack the computational power to calculate more decimals for the root? If so, what would be a good alternative for fsolve that could also calculate roots, just more accurately?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To better understand what happens, a first step would be to look at the infos of the run, which you can get by setting the `full_output` argument to True (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html for more details).

When starting with an initial point of 10 as you do, the algorithm claims to converge and do so in less evaluations than the maximum allocated, so it is not a problem of computing power.